# How to read a file using boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_source?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-iostreams

I need to use boost::iostreams::file_descriptor::handle_type in my app.
I try to read a file using following code, but it keeps looping in the while
loop (in.readsome() returns 0 ).

`using namespace boost::iostreams;`

```
file_descriptor_source source( "data.bin", never_close_handle);
stream_buffer<file_descriptor_source> stream(source);
std::istream in(&stream);

char buffer[1025];
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

while ( !in.eof() )
{
    streamsize read = in.readsome(&buffer[0], sizeof(buffer) - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reaching the end-of-file is not the only condition you should check for, since there could be other cases that you must handle too. For instance you may:

- check whether a non-recoverable error has occurred with `bad()`.
- check whether an error has occurred on the associated stream with `fail()`.

It is better to check the health of stream itself, as shown below:

```
while (in) {
    streamsize read = in.readsome(buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1);
    if (read > 0) {
        ...
    }
}
```

After exiting the loop, you could check the reason for exiting it with `eof()`, `fail()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Following statement does NOT read anything from the stream.

`streamsize read = in.readsome(&buffer[0], sizeof(buffer) - 1);`

And ALWAYS returns 0, that's why it loops forever.

Something wrong in the initialization of "in" object.
I do not know what is wrong.